# ItemTouchHelper callback

Tags: android

I have problems understanding which callback method of ItemTouchHelper is called when i swipe a carditem, but i dont finish the swipe and instead turn it back to the normal state.

What i have currently:

```
   @Override
   public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
       mCardItemAdapter.deleteCard(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(), mRecyclerView);
   }
```

which removes the item from the adapter.

And:

```
 @Override
 public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
     Log.d("dx =",""+dX);
     // Can be modified
     if(dX < -300) {
          View v = viewHolder.itemView;
          RelativeLayout mLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.card_item_layout_relative_layout);
          mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
      }
      super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
 }
```

What i want to achieve ? When i swipe, the background turns red, but when i release the swipe before `onSwiped` is called, the background stays red, but i want it to be white again.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Comment: `if(dx < -300){...} else { mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white); }`?

Comment: ok wtf? i had this before, but it didnt work O.o ok maybe i was dump . Write this as answer and i will mark it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional `else` clause:

`if(dx < -300){...} else { mLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white); }`